# setting line to read-only

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, scintilla

Ive been looking though the [QsciScintilla](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a451bcf235c2ad7628d32940a13d22116) API, and I want to know how to set a line in a text editor to read -only. I know it provides a setReadOnly function. But this sets the whole text editor to read-only.

Any suggestions on how to set a line to read-only?

Im using PQT4 Python 3x

Comment: I believe QsciScintilla gives you the option of intercepting user actions, no? You might be able to use this to veto an edit by the user: so if the user presses delete, bs, or a key, your function checks if it is on that line that is read-only, if yes then your code rejects that user action event.

Comment: @Schollii. But what if the user deletes or over-writes a larger chunk of text that happens to contain the "read-only" line? How will you prevent that?

Comment: @ekhumoro Same strategy: intercept delete on a selection, see if any of the selected lines is one of the read-only lines, if so, reject. Mind you, Pro-grammer might have other requirements not mentioned like show warning with ok/cancel, etc.

Comment: @Schollii. What should happen if you delete or insert lines above the read-only ones? I don't think tracking user actions alone is enough. The read-only lines would need to have a marker attached to them (there is an existing API for doing this) so that their positions could be tracked. But even if this was done, there is a lot of other built-in Scintilla functionality that would need to be disabled (or worked-around) in order to avoid clobbering things inadvertently. Your stategy would be a _lot_ easier to implement with a QTextEdit than with QScintilla.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this. There is a low-level feature in the underlying Scintilla control that can prevent the caret moving into an area of text - but it cannot prevent deletion of a broader area of text that *contains* a "read-only" part. But even if this was sufficient for your purposes, this feature can only be applied to ranges of *styled* text, not specific lines.

If you just want to associate some read-only text with a specific line, you could use an [annotation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#adacd79ec5e25430f0cbff34e6584afe7).

Comment: Thank You, do you by any chance know how to replace a line of text with another line of text?

Comment: @Pro-grammer. Yes, but it depends what you mean by "replace". Does the other line get deleted in the process? (This should really be a new question).

Comment: Yes, the line does get deleted!