# Removing a line from text

Tags: python, replace, pyqt, pyqt4, qscintilla

Say I have a text document. I have a line.I want to delete the text on that line and replace it with another text. How do I do this? There is nothing for this on the docs, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried open two files (source and destination), then using the `readline` function to go through each line on the source file, do your search/replace, and write it to the destination with `writeline`?

Comment: As its currently written, this question is a bit misleading. It's actually a follow-up from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22428152/984421) (see the comments).

Answer (score 2):

Untested: reads the lines of the file using .readlines() and then replaces the line number index in that list. Finally, it joins the lines and writes it to the file.

```
with open("file", "rw") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
    lines[line_number] = "replacement line"
    fp.seek(0)
    fp.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Comment: Despite being untested, the logic itself should work, even if the actual code might not, so +1.

Comment: If the replacement makes the contents shorter, won't some of the original file be left at the end because it was not overwritten?

Comment: @three_pineapples I think you're right. You'd probably want to remove the original instead of seek, but the basic idea remains so +1.

Comment: Although there is nothing wrong with this answer, it's not actually relevant to the question (which is about the qscintilla editor control).

Answer (score 2):

To replace a line in QScintilla, you need to first select the line, like this:

```
    # as an example, get the current line
    line, pos = editor.getCursorPosition()
    # then select it
    editor.setSelection(line, 0, line, editor.lineLength(line))
```

Once the line is selected, you can replace it with:

```
    editor.replaceSelectedText(text)
```

If you want to replace a line with another line (which will be removed in the process):

```
    # get the text of the other line
    text = editor.text(line)
    # select it, so it can be removed
    editor.setSelection(line, 0, line, editor.lineLength(line))
    # remove it
    editor.removeSelectedText()
    # now select the target line and replace its text
    editor.setSelection(target, 0, target, editor.lineLength(target))
    editor.replaceSelectedText(text)
```